# How to load @Configuration classes from separate Jars

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot main application, as well as a separate Maven module project that compiles as a separate Jar. The module has a Spring config class annotated with `@Configuration`, which I want to get loaded, when the main app loads.

Apparently, this does not happen out of the box (by just including the module to the main app). What else do I need to do, to get the module configuration class also get loaded by the main app?

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way is to scan the package that the @Configuration class is in.

```
@ComponentScan("com.acme.otherJar.config")
```

or to just load it as a spring bean:

```
 @Bean
 public MyConfig myConfig() {
     MyConfig myConfig = new MyConfig ();
     return myConfig;
 }
```

Where MyConfig is something like:

```
 @Configuration
 public class MyConfig {
     // various @Bean definitions ...
 }
```

See [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)

Comment: Hi Evgeni. I tried with @Bean approach in my Application.java class (which extends SpringBootServletInitializer), but my configuration is not loaded.

Comment: @Karna Hi, you should ask a question about your situation and provide more info there. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @Karna, I also try to load it with `@Bean` approach but it is not working. Did you succeed?

Comment: I just tried the @Bean option and it works like a charm. Thank-you very much

Answer (score 9):

@ComponentScan annotation will scan all classes with @Compoment or @Configuration annotation.

Then spring ioc will add them all to spring controlled beans.

If you want to only add specific configurations, you can use @import annotation.

example:

```
@Configuration
@Import(NameOfTheConfigurationYouWantToImport.class)
public class Config {

}
```

[@Import Annotation Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html)