# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation is not working inside a library

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Dears,

Need help in the below issue.

I'm trying to create a common authentication library to be used by multiple MFE Apps.
this library depends on Spring Web Security.
The problem that WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation is not applied if it's inside the library however if it's used directly into the app it will work.

Error: OPTIONS Methods is failing

More over Configure() method is called while starting the app in both cases (inside the library, inside the app directly)

Below is screen shot from Success request (inside the app directly)
[success inside app directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUp1a.png)

Below is screen shot from failed request (inside the library)
[Failure inside the library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cImtl.png)

Below is the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation:

```
  @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class JWTWebSecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtInMemoryUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenAuthorizationOncePerRequestFilter jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter;

    @Value("${jwt.get.token.uri}")
    private String authenticationPath;


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoderBean() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(jwtInMemoryUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoderBean());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        httpSecurity
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin()  //H2 Console Needs this setting
                .cacheControl(); //disable caching
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {


        webSecurity
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        authenticationPath
                )
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .and()
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/" //Other Stuff You want to Ignore
                )
                .and()
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**");//Should not be in Production!
    }




}
```

> Conclusion:  No I'm creating a library which is using spring security
>   inside this library the implementation of
>   WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. adding this library as a dependency for
>   another app, then it doesnot work. Although if used this
>   implementation directly on the app itself will work fine. Note: This
>   Library has the filter and everything related to JWT implementation
>   which will be a reusable library to multiple app.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you are saying that everything works inside spring but outside it does not. That you are trying to use the configurer outside spring. That is the only way it will work

Comment: Thanks efekctive, No I'm creating a library which is using spring security inside this library the implementation of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. adding this library as a dependency for another app, then it doesnot work. Although if used this implementation directly on the app itself will work fine. Note: This Library has the filter and everything related to JWT implementation which will be a reusable library to multiple app.

Comment: does this help? [how-to-load-configuration-classes-from-separate-jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272999/how-to-load-configuration-classes-from-separate-jars)

Comment: Is the library using the spring  security running inside running inside spring?

Comment: @DirkDeyne already added to scan the library, and Spring understand that there's implementation for WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter , as mentioned in the question that Configure() method has been called from the library.

Comment: @efekctive Yes Spring Security is a dependency for it, the Library also includes also the OncePerRequestFilter implementation

Comment: The question is if the second app is an spring app

Comment: Yes it's spring boot app

Comment: Then can you engage the debugger in any of the methods that perform the authentication/authorization?

Comment: the request didnot reach authz/authx method, as it fail in the filter

Comment: OncePerRequest is an interface. Your code is auto wiring that bean. Create a custom implementation of the interface place a breakpoint there and inspect the values received

Comment: This is already done, and the OPTIONS request is comming to the filter (which is part of the library also) but the filter did not follow the WebsecurityAdapter configuration to skip OPTIONS requets.

Comment: Then what you have is a badly applied config. Put a breakpoint in any/all of the JWTWebSecurityConfig methods to see if the container invokes them

Comment: Already done as mentioned in the post, and the container is calling configure methods.,